# CATiledLayer in NSView flashes on changing contentsScale

Tags: swift, macos, core-animation, catiledlayer

I have a **CATiledLayer** inside a **NSView** which is a **documentView** property of **NSScrollView**.
Storyboard setup is pretty straitforward: add **NSScrollView** to the default view controller and assign **View** class to the **NSView** of clipping view.

The following code draws a number of squares of random color. Scrolling works exactly as it should in **CATiledLayer** but zooming doesn't work very well:

[image]

Found tons of **CATiledLayer** problems and all the proposed solutions don't work for me (like subclassing with 0 **fadeDuration** or disabling **CATransaction** actions). I guess that **setNeedsDisplay()** screws it all but can't figure out the proper way to do that. If I use **CALayer** then I don't see the flashing issues but then I can't deal with large layers of thousands of boxes inside.

The **View** class source:

```
import Cocoa
import CoreGraphics
import Combine

let rows = 1000
let columns = 1000
let width = 50.0
let height = 50.0

class View: NSView {
    typealias Coordinate = (x: Int, y: Int)
    
    private let colors: [[CGColor]]
    private let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: width, height: height))
    private var store = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    private var scale: CGFloat {
        guard let scrollView = self.superview?.superview as? NSScrollView else { fatalError() }
        return NSScreen.main!.backingScaleFactor * scrollView.magnification
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        colors = (0..<rows).map { _ in (0..<columns).map { _ in .random } }
        super.init(coder: coder)
        
        setFrameSize(NSSize(width: width * CGFloat(columns), height: height * CGFloat(rows)))
        
        wantsLayer = true
        
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSScrollView.didEndLiveMagnifyNotification).sink { [unowned self] _ in
            self.layer?.contentsScale = scale
            self.layer?.setNeedsDisplay()
        }.store(in: &store)
    }
    
    override func makeBackingLayer() -> CALayer {
        let layer = CATiledLayer()
        layer.tileSize = CGSize(width: 1000, height: 1000)
        return layer
    }
    
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        guard let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext else { return }
        
        let (min, max) = coordinates(in: dirtyRect)
        
        context.translateBy(x: CGFloat(min.x) * width, y: CGFloat(min.y) * height)
        
        (min.y...max.y).forEach { row in
            context.saveGState()
            
            (min.x...max.x).forEach { column in
                context.setFillColor(colors[row][column])
                context.addRect(rect)
                context.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
                
                context.translateBy(x: width, y: 0)
            }
            
            context.restoreGState()
            context.translateBy(x: 0, y: height)
        }
    }
    
    private func coordinates(in rect: NSRect) -> (Coordinate, Coordinate) {
        var minX = Int(rect.minX / width)
        var minY = Int(rect.minY / height)
        var maxX = Int(rect.maxX / width)
        var maxY = Int(rect.maxY / height)
        
        if minX >= columns {
            minX = columns - 1
        }
        
        if maxX >= columns {
            maxX = columns - 1
        }
        
        if minY >= rows {
            minY = rows - 1
        }
        
        if maxY >= rows {
            maxY = rows - 1
        }
        
        return ((minX, minY), (maxX, maxY))
    }
}


extension CGColor {
    class var random: CGColor {
        let random = { CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) / 255.0 }
        return CGColor(red: random(), green: random(), blue: random(), alpha: random())
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you should have to listen to the `NSScrollView.didEndLiveMagnifyNotification` notification and manually trigger a redraw, this should be handled automatically if you setup the `levelsOfDetail` and `levelsOfDetailBias` respectively on the CATiledLayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to support zooming into a `CATiledLayer`, you set the layer's `levelOfDetailBias`. You don't need to observe the scroll view's magnification notifications, change the layers contentScale, or trigger manual redraws.

Here's a quick implementation that shows what kinds of dirtyRects you get at different zoom levels:

```
class View: NSView {
    
    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        wantsLayer = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        wantsLayer = true
    }
    
    override func makeBackingLayer() -> CALayer {
        let layer = CATiledLayer()
        layer.tileSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 400)
        layer.levelsOfDetailBias = 3
        return layer
    }
    
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        let context = NSGraphicsContext.current!
        let scale = context.cgContext.ctm.a
        
        NSColor.red.setFill()
        dirtyRect.frame(withWidth: 10 / scale, using: .overlay)
        
        NSColor.black.setFill()
        let string: NSString = "Scale: \(scale)" as NSString
        let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40 / scale)]
        let size = string.size(withAttributes: attributes)
        string.draw(at: CGPoint(x: dirtyRect.midX - size.width / 2, y: dirtyRect.midY - size.height / 2),
                    withAttributes: attributes)
    }
    
}
```

The current drawing contexts is already scaled to match the current zoom level (and the dirtyRect's get smaller and smaller for each level of detail down). You can extract the current scale from CGContext's transformation matrix as shown above, if needed.